# Instead of row number use the first cell number(Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have made a userform which automatically adds Textboxes & Labels depending on how many rows/Columns there are in the Sheet.

Now I have a problem, for example if I had **"Steve"** with number like **4**, it would not show the exact number in the cell Instead it will show the Row number.

[image: screenhoot1]

Excel Data Sheet Screenshot

[image: screenshot2]

So what I want is to fix the **Number :** Label and **also make the TextBox** for example now if i type 1 it will show the data for the Row number 1 i want to make it work with **"Steve"** writing a **"4"** instead of a **"2"** Which is the row number.

Here is the Userform code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'Exit Form
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    'Edit
    k = ScrollBar1.Value
    lcol = Sheet1.Range("DX2").End(xlToLeft).Column

    For j = 1 To lcol
        Sheet1.Cells(k + 1, j) = Me.Controls("textbox" & j)
    Next j

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    'Delete
    k = ScrollBar1.Value
    Sheet1.Cells(k + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()

Dim Rng As Range

    lcol = Sheet1.Range("DX2").End(xlToLeft).Column
    k = ScrollBar1.Value
    k2 = TextBox1000.Value

    label1000.Caption = "Number : " & k

    If k <> 0 And k2 <> 0 Then
        TextBox1000.Value = k
        For j = 1 To lcol
            Me.Controls("textbox" & j).Text = Sheet1.Cells(k, j).Offset(1, 0).Value
        Next j
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1000_Change()

    lcol = Sheet1.Range("DX2").End(xlToLeft).Column
    k = ScrollBar1.Value
    k2 = TextBox1000.Value
    label1000.Caption = "Number : " & k2

    If k2 <> "" Then
        ScrollBar1.Value = k2
        For j = 1 To lcol
            Me.Controls("textbox" & j).Text = Sheet1.Cells(k2, j).Offset(1, 0).Value
        Next j
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim myLabel As Control
Dim txtbox As Control

    k = ScrollBar1.Value
    label1000.Caption = "Number : " & k
    lcol = Sheet1.Range("DX2").End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 1 To lcol

        Set myLabel = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.label.1", "label" & i, True)

        myLabel.Left = 250
        myLabel.Top = 12 + (i * 20)
        myLabel.Width = 150
        myLabel.Height = 15

        Set txtbox = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "TextBox" & i, True)

        txtbox.Left = 50
        txtbox.Top = 10 + (i * 20)
        txtbox.Width = 180
        txtbox.Height = 60

    Next i

    For j = 1 To lcol

        With Frame1.Controls("label" & j)'Formating Labels
            .Caption = Sheet1.Cells(1, j).Value
            .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Size = 11
            .FontName = "Times New Roman"
            .ForeColor = vbRed
        End With

        With Frame1.Controls("TextBox" & j) 'Formating TextBoxes
            .Text = Sheet1.Cells(1, j).Offset(1, 0).Value
            .TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Size = 11
            .FontName = "Times New Roman"
        End With

        With Frame1.Controls("TextBox1")'Make textbox1 not editable
            .Enabled = False
        End With

        With Frame1.Controls("TextBox3")'Make textbox3 not editable
            .Enabled = False
        End With

    Next j

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say

```
Label1000.Caption = "Number : " & Sheet1.Cells(k + 1, 1).Value
```

Comment: I mean like do u see the Textbox? like for example i want to type for example number 4 i want it to get the data for number 4 but that worked as for the Number : label

Comment: For example this : Me.Controls("textbox" & j).Text = Sheet1.Cells(k, j).Offset(1, 0).Value